# How to sum values of two columns by an ID column, keeping some columns with repeated values and excluding others?

Tags: dataframe

I need to organize a large df adding values of a column by a column ID (the ID is not sequencial), keeping some columns of the df that have repeated values by ID and excluding column that have different values by ID. Below I inserted a reproducible example and the output I need. I think there is a simple way to do that, but I am not soo familiar with R.

```
df=read.table(textConnection("

ID       spp      effort   generalist        specialist

1          a          10        1          0

1          b          10        1          0

1          c          10        0          1

1          d          10        0          1

2          a          16        1          0

2          b          16        1          0

2          e          16        0          1

"), header = TRUE)
```

The output I need:

```
ID  effort  generalist  specialist
1   10  2   2
2   16  2   1
```

Comment: Actually I got... but I'm sure someone else have a more direct way to do it. `library(data.table)
df <- data.table(df)
df1 <- df[,list(special = sum(specialist)), by = c("ID")]
df2 <- df[,list(general = sum(generalist)), by = c("ID")]


df3<-unique(df,by="ID")

df4<-merge(df3,df1,by="ID")
df5<-merge(df4,df2,by="ID")

subset(df5,select=-c(spp,specialist,generalist))`

Comment: I believe that could be group by id and effort columns, then generate aggregate summary for generalist and specialist columns. And you can apply on the programming language you are using.